# What is an actual difference between redux and a state machine (e.g. xstate)?

Tags: javascript, redux, state-machine, xstate

I am working on investigation of one front-end application of medium complexity. At this moment it is written in pure javascript, it has a lot of different event-based messages connecting few main parts of this application.

We decided that we need to implement some kind of state container for this application in scope of further refactoring. Previously I had some experience with redux and ngrx store (which actually follows the same principles).

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/) is an option for us, but one of the developers proposed using a state-machine based library, in particular the [xstate library](https://xstate.js.org/docs/).

I've never worked with xstate, so I found it interesting and started reading documentation and looking at different examples. Looked promising and powerful, but at some point I understood that I don't see any significant difference between it and redux.

I spent hours trying to find an answer, or any other information comparing xstate and redux. I didn't find any clear information, except some articles like ["get from redux to a state machine"](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/getting-from-redux-to-state-machine-with-stent), or links to libraries focused on using redux and xstate **together** (quite weird).

If someone can describe the difference or tell me when developers should choose xstate - you are welcome to.

Comment: The official docs actually say that you should treat your redux reducers as a state machine https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#treat-reducers-as-state-machines

Comment: I think the libraries you mention might be for using xstate as an effect management system (alternative to thunk, saga, epic, etc.)

Answer (score 389, accepted):

I created XState, but I'm not going to tell you whether to use one over the other; that depends on your team. Instead, I'll try to highlight some key differences.

| Redux | XState |
| --- | --- |
| essentially a state container where events (called *actions* in Redux) are sent to a reducer which update state | also a state container, but separates finite state (e.g., `"loading"`, `"success"`) from "infinite state", or context (e.g., `items: [...]`) |
| does not dictate how you define your reducers - they are plain functions that return the next state given the current state and event (action) | a "reducer with rules" - you define legal transitions between finite states due to events, and also which actions should be executed in a transition (or on entry/exit from a state) |
| does *not* have a built-in way to handle side-effects; there are many community options, like redux-thunk, redux-saga, etc. | makes actions (side-effects) declarative and explicit - they are part of the `State` object that is returned on each transition (current state + event) |
| currently has no way to visualize transitions between states, since it does not discern between finite and infinite state | has a visualizer: https://statecharts.github.io/xstate-viz which is feasible due to the declarative nature |
| the implicit logic/behavior represented in reducers can't be serialized declaratively (e.g., in JSON) | machine definitions, which represent logic/behavior, can be serialized to JSON, and read from JSON; this makes behavior very portable and configurable by external tools |
| not strictly a state machine | adheres strictly to the W3C SCXML specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/scxml/ |
| relies on the developer to manually prevent impossible states | uses statecharts to naturally define boundaries for handling events, which prevents impossible states and can be statically analyzed |
| encourages the use of a single, "global" atomic store | encourages the use of an Actor-model-like approach, where there can be many hierarchical statechart/"service" instances that communicate with each other |

I will add more key differences to the docs this week.

Comment: Finally someone using FSM and SCXML for front development... man you saved my life, I'm going to study your library. I don't like redux for some reasons (first it confuse event and action terms) and second it "model" complex states with million flags (verbose and imho incorrect).

Comment: @Mike76 XState integrates with Redux dev tools.

Comment: I have now tried XState + Redux DevTools. It works quite well, but some features seem to be missing. For example, XState + Redux DevTools does not support features like "state replay" where a sequence of previous states gets replayed. Is this due to implementation limitations?

Comment: @Mike76 See this on time travelling in Redux and XState: https://github.com/statelyai/xstate/issues/906#issuecomment-569760677

Answer (score 37):

**State machine** does not tell (force) you to have Unidirectional data flow. It has nothing to do with data flow. It is more about **constraining state changes** and about **state transitions**. So, generally only some parts of the application would be designed with State machines, only and only if you need to *constraint/forbid* some state changes and you are *interested* in transitions.

Beware that with state machines, if for some reason (external API dependency etc...), there is chance that app might get locked in a state where it can't transition to another state because of constraints, you have to solve it.

**But** if you are only interested in last app state itself, instead of *state transitions*, and state constraints do not matter, then you better be not using state machine and directly be updating state itself (**you can still wrap state in a Singleton class update through Action classes**).

---

On the other hand, **Redux** is **Unidirectional architecture framework**. Unidirectional architectures enforce you to have single direction of data flow. In Redux, it starts with `User->View->(Action)->Store->Reducer->(Middleware)->Store->(State)->View`. Like State Machines, you can trigger side effects with Middlewares in Redux. You can constraint/forbid State transitions, if you want. **Different from State Machine**, Redux forces unidirectional data flow, **pure**! reducer functions, immutable state objects, single observable app state.

Comment: Isn't the FSM just a graph that can drive Redux? Navigation is a FSM because you have the back button. Unless you disable the back button, even in Redux, you have a FSM. Redux is an immutable data pattern with good constraints. So as you navigate through your FSM (library or self-written, even if unintentional) Redux prevents side-effects. Redux captures only the unidirectonal portion of data flow. It is not pure.

Answer (score 1):

few of my points below.

- The UI-state and business/backend state are coupled together in redux. Because of this every update on the ui or business state creates a data update in the redux store.
- Xstate decouples UI state and  backend state.
- In redux all nodes are present inside a root node. Xstate decentralises and distributes data inside independent Machines.
- Application can only transition between the states defined already. So any error or bug can be fixed in the Machine itself.
- Internal states are managed by the Machine itself in Xstate. Redux represents new states as flags.
- Renderer agonistic - keeping as much of the state hoisted into Machines, and if we need, we can switch rendering frameworks relatively easy (eg from react to vue).
- Contexts provides concrete class to present a single interface to the outside world.

Comment: I actually am familiar with both. And that is not quite accurate. React is mostly just rendering HTML as a function. React does provide minimum state handling intended for simple UI elements. For "business rules" there are many third party libraries including xstate.

Comment: This compares redux and xstate. Specifically to state management inside react apps.